# jQuery faking click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Lets say I have code:

```
$('#target').click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

I want that after page is loaded `#target` would be auto clicked, yet click function remain active.

For example same button for play and stop. This would launch play method but if pressed again would stop that.

Should I just trow it to separate method or if there is single line call for such event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// when the page is ready
$(function() {
    $('#target').click(function() {
        alert('Handler for .click() called.');
    });

    // trigger click handler for #target
    $("#target").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

It's quite simple and you almost had it...

```
$('#target').click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
}).click();
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gislikonrad/xqKBE/

Comment: Although it is more elegant solution, having click separate feels more secure and flexible.

Comment: The accepted answer is less efficient... At least take $('#trigger') and put it in a variable and call click and trigger on that...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#target').trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should the use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event (not to be confused with toggle for showing and hiding!) as this handles multiple functions off the same event. You can then call [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click) after binding to call it once automatically:

```
$('#target').toggle(function() {
  $(this).text('Stop');
}, function() {
  $(this).text('Play');
}).click();
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TUBqy/)